# Matching ADR with original Dialogue

Tags: noise-reduction, adr

Alright, I'll admit - I have no idea what I'm doing here.  I could really use some tips.

I'm having trouble matching some ADR recordings with the original dialogue recordings.  The scene takes place on a beach which means there is no need for reverb (as far as I know).

Follow the link below for a snippet of the audio.  The first line of dialogue you hear is the original, and the second line is the ADR.  You can tell there is an unwanted reverb on the ADR track which would be nice to get rid of.  I also find the ADR recording doesn't sound as 'big' as the original.

https://soundcloud.com/beatbell/beach-adr/s-7IBW4

All I am using right now to process the ADR is:

- WNS (Waves Noise Suppressor)

  - to remove as much reverb that came with the room during ADR recording
    [image]
- EQ

  - To try and 'thin out' the ADR to match original

**Any tips or tricks to be shared with matching ADR recordings to the originals?

https://soundcloud.com/beatbell/beach-adr/s-7IBW4

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

it's always a very tricky situation when you have to work with unwanted reverb. I would say it's almost impossible to get rid of a serious reverb but to some extent it can be done using SPL De-Verb.
You can download a demo here:
https://www.plugin-alliance.com/en/downloads.html#spl_de-verb
I think it costs 60USD or something like that and it can be very useful.

There's of course Izotope RX3 Advanced with Dereverb. 
https://www.izotope.com/en/products/audio-repair/rx/features/
I think you can get 10-days fully working trial. It's pricey though.

I've heard that Unveil is a good one but I haven't tried it yet.
http://www.zynaptiq.com/unveil/

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand you want to get rid of reverb (reflections?) on the ADR track. but in the current snippet i don't hear any reverb and if there is any it's masked by the waves and crackling of the fire. do you hear reverb on the ADR source material? perhaps post that?
what i don't understand is this: 
"I also find the ADR recording doesn't sound as 'big' as the original." 
But say that you use EQ to 'thin out' the ADR, this is counterproductive, the set recording sounds really nice and full (albeit soft). 
maybe you're overprocessing or to focussed on the sound, if it works, don't touch it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's other issues before you tackle reverb. Mainly the volume and EQ. The original sounds much bigger. I think the reverb will get masked by the ambience.